Rubber boat nomenclature: Differences in American English?
What's the difference between a rubber/inflatable boat, a rubber/inflatable dinghy and a rubber/inflatable raft appearance-wise? What visual clues do native English speakers look out for to pinpoint which word should be used?
They both look they same and purpose-wise, they overlap. I cannot tease out the difference between them.
Can you perhaps tell me if there are any visual clues based on which native speakers determine when to use which? (Maybe I have overlooked them)
Thank you in advance!

Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

The above will save you from obvious answers such as that rubber boats are made from natural or synthetic rubber, or that dinghies and rafts are types of boat.

Being made of rubber doesn't alter the working definitions of "boat," "dinghy," and "raft." When asking about the meaning of words, please start by looking them up in a dictionary, and if questions remain, tell in your question about the confusing results you found. Then answers can address those findings instead of just giving you the same information you found confusing. Voting to close for now; please use the "Edit" button to add this info and make the question valid for answering.

I have done research. I came here because that was all in vain.

This requirement isn't just to make you jump through a hoop for no reason, but so you can show what you found so that answers can address what you found. A boat is a boat, a dinghy is a dinghy, and a raft is a raft. Clearly you either found vague definitions or misunderstood them, so please provide those definitions so the vagary or misunderstanding can be addressed.

Deleting your previous question (after it got an answer) and then reposting substantially the same question was not cool.

@Laurel Oh, dear, all that effort I made for nothing. Thanks for pointing that out.

The first point is the noun:
Among the types of craft that can go in the water for people to use are: a raft, a dinghy, a boat.
So, a raft is today is usually a flat craft made of rubber or wood or plastic or bamboo or some type of wood.
So, one for playing or just floating in the water will be like this and is inflatable and made of plastic  . That is what makes it float:

a plastic raft for pool or lake/ocean


a bamboo raft


a log raft



All of those are: Merriam Webster
: a flat structure (as of wood) for support or transportation on water
So the semantic trait for a raft is: flat structure, floatable, used for support or transportation

But there are also rafts made of rubber for whitewater rafting that look like this:


[These types of raft are always made of rubber and are inflatable.]
So, now we add a semantic trait: flat, inflatable sides/ends, rubber

A dinghy is a craft with sides and looks like a rowboat:


Dinghies are often towed behind a sailboat as an emergency craft and may have an outboard motor but are also used for all sorts of recreation purposes themselves like fishing and are even sometimes equipped with a sail. They can also be rowed:

Boats: generally, boats per se are not inflatable EXCEPT for the Zodiacs, used by regular people for recreational purposes and also by the armed forces. They are made of rubber and their pontoons (the "tubes") are filled with air.
See the range of inflatable Zodiac boats here: ZodiaC
Here is a typical one:

A dinghy can be made of aluminum, plastic or wood.
To summarize: a raft is not a boat as it is too specific to be one.  A dinghy is a type of small boat and has sides. Some of them that are really Zodiacs (with poontoons) can be inflatable. The aluminum dinghies are not inflatable.
Recreational rafts are inflatable and made of plastic or rubber.
Other types (wooden or log raft) are not.
Dinghies are wood, rubber, or aluminum. The rubber ones are inflatable and generally associated with a Zodiac or Zodiac-type craft.
Dinghies are small boats. Rafts are not boats but they are a water craft.
Visual clues for a raft: flatness on the water and  Generally, no sides though some have them.
This nomenclature is NOT AmE. It's just English.

See, I would argue that a boat is, well, as MW says, "a small vessel for travel on water." That is, if it floats and you can get in it and you can reasonably get from place to place, it's a boat. Thus a pool float isn't a boat (usually/arguably), but a coracle, a bamboo raft, a rubber whitewater rafting raft, and a lifeboat all are. Meanwhile from reading Patrick O'Brian I know that ships hate being called boats, and may draw distinctions about how many masts and so forth. But for general purposes, "small" is enough to distinguish boat from ship.

One reasonable distinction I've seen for rafts vs. boats is how they derive their buoyancy - boats usually have a denser-than-water solid hull that excludes water and which would sink if filled, while rafts are usually made of material that's positively buoyant in the first place, like bamboo or inflatable tubing. A raft may or may not have sides, but doesn't require them to stay afloat, unlike a boat.

@NuclearHoagie The semantic traits are different. That's enough.

@AndyBonner I'm not writing a treatise, just the basic ideas. I myself could write an entire book and find all kinds of exceptions. The point is a raft is not a boat, a dinghy is a small boat and I won't define boat as we presumably all know what a boat is.

I know that a raft can be made of wood and that a boat can be made of various materials! But I'd like to specifically focus the difference between inflatable/ rubber boats, dinghies and rafts made of rubber (as the name implies)

@Idk29 That comment is quite confusing. Because inflatable/rubber boat as written means in written English: inflatable boat OR rubber boat. So, state it more clearly. An inflatable boat (its pontoons) are made of rubber. durable synthetic rubber, that is.

You should be able to tell the difference between a dinghy, which is a BOAT, and a raft. I gave enough visual clues.

@NuclearHoagie That is not a visual clue; that's physics. And of course, the point of a raft is for it to stay afloat...

Regarding the differences between several types of inflatable, rubber watercraft they are all probably quite similar to each other in appearance. They will be bulbous and be constructed of compartments to hold the air inside that will generally be tubular in shape.
In these cases, the other qualifier in the name (raft, dinghy, boat) will probably have more to do with their intended purpose than their shape or appearance. Rafts are usually not equipped with a propulsion system, and so are often intended for use on rivers, where they can float downstream, or in the case of a pool raft, just stay in one place to support a person relaxing. A boat or dinghy would normally have some means of propulsion, like a motor, sail or oars, so that it could be moved in the direction chosen by its occupants, regardless of the motion of the water it's travelling on.
